# How to create sftpuser vor /var/www Directory?

Tags: sftp

I'm setting up a new server and want to have a sftpuser for our /var/www/ directory to upload webcontent without installing a ftp server like proFTPD.

Did u can help me to do this? I just know how about with a FTP Server like proFTPD.

Best regards

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create user:

```
sudo useradd -d /var/www username
```

Set them a password:

```
sudo passwd username
```

Open the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file and append the below given code. (Remember to replace "username" with username you have created):

```
subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match User username
ChrootDirectory %h
AllowTCPForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Restart the ssh :

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Now it should work. There may be some ownership problems (just chown things for the user if they really need to use that).

Comment: In the /etc/ssh/sshd_config , did you delete it all and put that, or did you append the configuration? (you need to append it in the final, and put the username correctly).

Comment: just had two times X11 Forwarding in ^^ fixed and running :) Did u can jail the user that he cant move above /var/www? :)

Comment: Yep, setting the home directory of a user means that he has control on that and lower directories(except for files that have permissions out of his reach). He can't go in /var  or / if you don't let him.